# Clicking a button changes background-color of other div?

Tags: javascript, html, button, colors, background

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#button').click(function() {
  var colors = ["#16A085","#2980b9","#34495e"]  
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length);           
  $('.navbar-inverse').css("background-color", colors[rand]);

});
```

What is the error? I want the background-color of .navbar-inverse to change when clicking #button.

Comment: It works here http://jsbin.com/zuhec/1/edit, problem must be somewhere else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button').click(function() {
        var colors = ["#16A085","#2980b9","#34495e"]; // here
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length);           
        $('.navbar-inverse').css("background-color", colors[rand]);
    }); // here
});
```

1. Missing semicolon at the end of 3. row
2. Missing "});" at the end of click callback